# Linux .NET 6 exe seeks DLL in current dir instead of its own

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, working-directory

I just upgraded a .NET Core application from .NET 5 to 6. I used to start this application via a symbolic link in my home directory.

However, after updating the link to the newly-created .NET 6 version of my program, I get this:

```
$ ln -S ProgramName /home/UserName/Dev/ProgramName/bin/Debug/net6.0/ProgramName
$ ./ProgramName myargs
The application to execute does not exist: '/home/UserName/ProgramName.dll'.
```

Why is it looking for its namesake DLL in the current directory now?

I didn't have this behavior in the .NET 5 version, this seems like a big regression. How can I fix or work around this problem?

Comment: Try recreate link with `-s` flag. You created a hard link, it makes a copy of original file, afaik.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I had used the wrong flag in the command I actually typed (`-S` instead of `-s`). Looks like I had swapped link source and destination too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the correct link command was:

```
ln -s /home/UserName/Dev/ProgramName/bin/Debug/net6.0/ProgramName ProgramName
```

(confusion resulting from the order being swapped relative to Windows's symbolic link command line)